# mousePosition on World Space canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a canvas set to rendermode World Space set as child to a gameObject. I'd like a UI element on this canvas to follow the mousePointer. So how do I get the position of the mouse on the canvas?

Comment: [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/785218/how-to-get-mouse-location-on-world-canvas-unity-46.html) might help

Answer (score 0):

If your Canvas' `RenderMode` is set to `ScreenSpaceOverlay`, this will do:

```
 transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
```

Documentation:http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/RenderMode.html